# Laravel Routing error

Tags: php, laravel-5

I'm just getting started with Laravel. I've just installed it. But when I'm making a new route it's not working, it's saying:

> The requested URL /laravel/public/test was not found on this server.

This is currently my routes.php:

```
 Route::get('/', function () {
    >     return view('welcome'); });

    > Route::get('/test', function () {
    >     return view('test'); });
```

And of course I've made a view called test. When I go to:

> http://localhost/laravel/public/test

I'm seeing the Laravel start template. But when I go to:

```
> http://localhost/laravel/public/test
```

It's not working?

And why can I also visit:

> http://localhost/laravel.dev/

Thankyou.

EDIT:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would imagine the issue is with your .htaccess.

```
This likely works
> http://localhost/laravel/public/index.php/test
```

Now your .htaccess should contain logic to pass all requests to the index.php already by default. If that's the case, then it's likely an issue with your Virtual Host entry not having `AllowOverride All` within the `<Directory>` block.

Note `AllowOverride All` is not a good choice for a production environment.

Comment: Thankyou that works, but I do not quite understand what you mean with "AllowOverride All". Could you take a look at my .htacces (please see my edit)

Comment: @jamie Well...the AllowOverride All protion belongs inside of the `VirtualHost` declaration for your localhost. This way, the .htaccess can make modifications to certain server-side configurations. Without the `AllowOverride All` you may not be able to. Also always make sure that mod_rewrite is enabled.